Undercover agent joins reality show where they fight to the death
At some point in the movie, two things happen I can recall:
They find some phsyco criminal, bust him out of a moving van (he's going to his death sentence), and get him to fight in this cage for viewers.
The main lady ends up liking him and she helps him.
At the end they escape and the undercover people find out where the secret location is where they are doing the fighting.
I'm NOT talking about Gamer.
Cheers.


Arena (2011)

From IMDb: David Lord finds himself forced into the savage world of a
  modern gladiatorial arena, where men fight to the death for the
  entertainment of the online masses.

Here's the trailer, and the movie's Wikipedia page will confirm your other plot points.

You are a god Rumandwrite!

@user7751 ... If this answer satisfies your request, please be kind and select it as such!
